# Possible to write Code from cells to VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering how I would call something in VBA to write its code while running? So I mean if I had the **text** in A1 read:

```
sub Write()
   Call OtherScript
End Sub
```

So again that is text inside the cell not in a VBA script. And then in a script while its running it Calls "A1" and the code that's in A1 gets run through VBA without having to actually put it in there.

This is not a real code obviously, I am really just trying to find out if this is possible. A friend that helps me learn to code and works me through a lot of VBA's said he does not know how that would work so Im posting it here to see if possible.

Comment: `Select case Range("A1").Value` / `Case "ThisScript"` / `call ThisScript` / `Case "OtherScript"` / `call OtherScript` and so on? There are probably better ways to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Not clear what you really want accomplishing. To run different procedures according to value of a specific cell? If not, please better clarify what you need. To have a string which to be a sub code and transform it in a procedure? Even a new procedure can be written in code, but almost nothing is clear in your question, no offence...

Comment: I am curious. Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Please, try the following code. Before running it, write in a cell:

```
sub WriteSomething() 
   Call OtherScript
End Sub
```

You cannot create a function/sub named `Write` because this word is illegal, meaning something else in VBA.

and in the next cell (on the same row):

```
sub OtherScript()
   MsgBox "Hello!"
End Sub
```

I used "K2". Use it too, or adapt the range from the code. You should also have a `Module3` standard module. Please, update the module name with the one existing in your `vbProject`. Anyhow, the code can also create the module...

Copy the next code and run it:

```
Sub write_Run_Subs()
   'It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility x.x'
   Dim vbProj As VBProject, objMod As VBComponent, mdlName As String
   Dim rngStr As Range, strSub1 As String, strSub2 As String
   
   Set rngStr = Range("K2")
   strSub1 = rngStr.value
   strSub2 = rngStr.Offset(0, 1).value
   mdlName = "Module3" 'of course, it have to exist in ThisWorkbook vbProject
   Set vbProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
   Set objMod = vbProj.VBComponents(mdlName)
   objMod.CodeModule.AddFromString strSub1
   objMod.CodeModule.AddFromString strSub2
   
   Application.Run mdlName & ".WriteSomething"
End Sub
```

It is only a simple code without too much error handling, but it should work... If you run it twice, it will insert two such subs, if not preliminarily check their existence.

If adding the necessary reference looks complicated, please firstly run the following code, which will add it:

```
Sub addExtenssibilityReference()
   'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3':
   ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
        GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", _
        Major:=5, Minor:=3
End Sub
```